# typeorm one to one relation update

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I encountered the following problem:
When I try to update an image (FIle entity) that has one to one relation with User then in the database I have a new User ID saved instead of keeping the existing ID, I would love for help.

Entites:

```
    @OneToOne(type => User, user => user.file)
    user: User | User['id'];
```

```
 @OneToOne(type => FileModel, file => file.user, {onUpdate: 'CASCADE', onDelete: 'CASCADE'})
    @JoinColumn()
    file: FileModel;
```

Code:

```
    async update(newUserData, userId: number, picture?) {
        const userExists = await User.findOne(userId, {relations: ["file"]});
        if (picture) {
            if (userExists.file) {
                await fileService.removeS3(userExists.file.fileName);
                await fileService.deleteFile(userExists.file.id);
            }
            const fileModel = new FileModel();
            const {Location, Key} = await fileService.uploadImage(picture.filename, picture.originalname);
            fileModel.fileName = Key;
            fileModel.filePath = Location;
            userExists.file = await fileService.saveImage(fileModel);
        }
        return await User.save({...userExists, ...newUserData});
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you're passing the userExist.id to `User.save({...userExists, ...newUserData})`. I guess the assignment you did override it with null value.